# How to make max-width property robust to php calls / dynamic css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have tried adding custom CSS in page builder mode using:

```
#content {
    max-width: 2000px;
}
```

When it stays in page builder mode, the effect is as desired. However, as soon as I publish changes, the page reverts to the previous (smaller) `max-width` setting. To investigate, I went with the inspect element approach and noticed that the `max-width` property for `#content` is still coming from style.css, and not my custom CSS. For robustness, I also added that style rule to Global Settings, but nothing changed. The good news is I was able to experiment in the dev tool window and noticed that when I unchecked the `max-width` property governed by style.css, my custom style rule is applied. So at least I know that if I can isolate that particular style.css section, I should be good to go.

That's what I tried to do, I went in to the Lyrical theme folder and changed the `max-width` property as desired and saved changes, however to my surprise and dismay, the page still kept the previous (smaller) `max-width` setting. After more inspect element work, I noticed that the style sheet has a particular `?ver=xxxx` suffix and I suspect that has something to do with why my changes are not showing up. I cannot find any file named style.css?ver=xxxx, so I guess it's being dynamically generated on page load or something like that. These are just my hunches; I don't have an extensive background in php or anything beyond basic javascript so it's particularly hard to troubleshoot at the moment.

**Question:** How can I make sure that my published page applies my `max-width` property? I'm not sure if I should investigate more about the style.css version number or if I should look at things more from the php side. I now realize how little I understand about what's under the hood here. Any help, big or small would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to declare your css rule, in this case you should to:

1. add this code anywhere you adding

   ```
   #content{
      max-width: 2000px !important;
   }
   ```

   `!important` will rewrite other `css rules`, which haven't got it's. More info about it here: [!important where use and why](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).
2. Other way is to find some css file, which is rendering after your `style.css` file and add your code there without `!important`. That will rewrite your `style.css` rules.
3. Add your code at the end of your css file. Than you can be sure, that your `css` will rewrite others.

If you want to add that `css` only for one page, you should to find in that page some specific `css class or id` for that page. Because you're using `wordpress`, you can find some of it in your `body tag`, like `page-id-1`. Instead of `1` use your page id and add your css even in your style css file( not recommend to change it. Better add code into your `Customize-> Additiona Css` or your theme may have some settings for adding `custom css` ).

```
    .page-id-1 #content{
       max-width: 2000px !important;
    }
```